# Swagger / Postman Collection for AWS APIs?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, swagger

I want to use a tool like postman to invoke REST APIs against various AWS services.

However, I can't seem to find pre-built Postman collections or even Swagger definitions of the AWS APIs.

I could obviously handcraft each request, but does anyone know if there is an easier way ? (like generating Swagger by introspecting the SDKs or something along those lines ? )

Comment: Unofficial community supported collections: https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/workspace/amazon-web-services-aws/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to find all AWS APIs swagger definitions here:

https://github.com/APIs-guru/openapi-directory/tree/master/APIs/amazonaws.com

Guy